# Correct way to handle screen sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I started developing for iOS around 8 years ago and got back into it a couple years ago. Since the time I started a while back, a lot has changed, in particularly the number of screen sizes we have now.

Right now I am designing multiple view controllers in the storyboard for each screen size. I start designing the screen based on the iPhone 6 Plus, my device, and then make new view controllers with different size frames and scale its subviews according the percentage difference between the screen I'm working on vs. my iPhone 6 Plus screen.

Here is the code I have which runs when a button is tapped. It determines the user's screen size and displays the appropriate view controller.

```
CGRect          screenBounds    = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIStoryboard    *storyboard     = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

MyViewController *myViewController;

if (screenBounds.size.width == 320.0 && screenBounds.size.height == 480.0)
    myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhone4MyViewController"];
else if (screenBounds.size.width == 320.0 && screenBounds.size.height == 568.0)
    myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhone5MyViewController"];
else if (screenBounds.size.width == 375.0 && screenBounds.size.height == 667.0)
    myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhone6MyViewController"];
else if (screenBounds.size.width == 414.0 && screenBounds.size.height == 736.0)
    myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhone6PlusMyViewController"];

// Etc. for iPad's, then present
```

My question is, is this the appropriate way to design and present screens of different sizes? This just seems like doing way more work than I really should being doing.

Comment: Now we got new thing for designing called Auto layout & constraints. You no need to create nib for each device.one design will adopt for all

Comment: r u supporting portrait and landscape both?

Comment: @DSDharma OK, is it hard to learn? How long does it take, you think, to have a good understanding of it? Right now it seems to me doing it the current way I am would be faster than having to learn something entirely new because I'm trying to get this app out there as fast as I can.

Comment: @elk_cloner No, just portrait.

Comment: it's easy not hard.check more about auto layout there is lot of tutorials is available.

Comment: @DSDharma OK thank you!

Comment: Lol, I started doing iOS app development last year. Now seeing your code tells me how much code I have to write, if there is no auto layout concept. Auto layout is much easier then implementing the above code man. You will love that.

Comment: @jegadeesh Haha lucky you! It's like a time machine coming from 8 years ago, but to you, auto layout is apparently the standard. I just have to learn it, but I am concerned about the time to learn it versus doing it my way right now and getting it out there faster. What do you think? Is it pretty fast to learn and easy to get used to?

Comment: It won't be a tough thing to learn(for you especially). It can be learnt pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to use **Auto-layout**.

Secondly while playing with autolayout you will see you can't set your left/right/top/bottom distance according to aspect ratio of your device size.

Let's say you have a button which has left distance(**leading constraint**) 40 from it's superview. You can't use aspect ratio according to device size using autolayout.

**How to resolve this?**

You have to programmatically calculate that distance according to device size.

Create some constants like this.

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_IPHONE_6P (SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH/736.0)
```

Now if your base layout is iphone6Plus then just multiply **SCREEN_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_IPHONE_6P** with your **left distance(leading constraint)**. here **736** is iphone 6 plus height.

like this

```
yourButtonLeftDistance.constant = 30*SCREEN_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_IPHONE_6P
```

That's it. You are now supporting all devices in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create separate xib's for iPhone 5,6,7. You can simple use Auto layouts , constraints and size classes.